# Prevent certain optionset changes in CRM via plugin

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

Is it possible to have a plugin intervene when someone is editing an optionset?

I would have thought crm would prevent the removal of optionset values if there are entities that refer to them, but apparently this is not the case (there are a number of orphaned fields that refer to options that no longer exist).  Is there a message/entity pair that I could use to check if there are entities using the value that is to be deleted/modified and stop it if there are?

Comment: I've never heard of an event regarding customizations like this (that you could register a plugin against - I'm not listing this as an answer in case it does exist though).  In general, anyone who has rights to change optionset values should be technical enough to understand the implications of doing so and should do their due diligence before messing with the data model.  Sorry I cant help more than that.

Comment: In theory the data admin does know the implications, but people being forgetful results in inevitable problems like this.  Unless the system stops a user from doing something silly, they WILL do it given enough time.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is possible, but you could attempt to create a plugin on the Execute Method, and check the input parameters in the context to determine what the Request Type that is being processed is.  Pretty sure you'll be wanting to look for either `UpdateAttributeRequest` for local OptionSets, or potentially `UpdateOptionSetRequest` for both.  Then you could run additional logic to determine what values are changing, and ensuring the database values are correct.

The big caveat to this, is if you even have a moderate amount of data, I'm guessing you'll hit the 2 minute limit for plugin execution and it will fail.

Comment: This sounds plausible, I'll check it tomorrow.  Fortunately we are a small organization that has records measured in the thousands, not millions/billions so the time limit shouldn't be an issue (fingers crossed).  I'll mark this as the answer if it works!

Comment: Ok so I finally got around to trying your suggestion and unfortunately I couldn't get it to work.  I verified that my plugin was being activated, just clicking on various screens activated the 'execute' step.  Strangely adding/editing/removing options from an optionset doesn't trigger an 'Execute' message.  I also tried 'SetState' and 'SetStateDynamicEntity' out of desperation but no luck.

Comment: Thanks for the idea, I don't think I can mark this as the answer but I will upvote it since it was useful in eliminating possibilities.